# await on observable to complete

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, system.reactive, observable

I have a method that do some work asynchronously with use of observable. I would like to know what is the best way to make this method *async*, so that I will be able to *await* on it and do some work after observable completes.

My first try was to use *await* on observable.

```
public async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    var observable = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("OnNext");
            o.OnNext(1);
            o.OnError(new Exception("exception in observable logic"));
            //o.OnCompleted();
        });    
        return Disposable.Empty;
    });

    //observable = observable.Publish().RefCount();

    observable.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
    Console.WriteLine("Awaiting...");
    await observable;
    Console.WriteLine("After Awaiting...");
}
```

Depending on the scenario I had different issues with that approach (+/- means that this part of code is uncommented/commented):

1. +OnNext +OnCompleted -OnError -RefCount: *OnNext* was invoked 2 times (observable was subscribed 2 times). This is what I would like to avoid.
2. +OnNext +OnCompleted -OnError +RefCount: When I use *RefCount()* method the code works.
3. -OnNext +OnCompleted -OnError +RefCount: "Sequence contains no element" exception is thrown when my observable doesn't raise *OnNext*.
4. +OnNext -OnCompleted +OnError -RefCount: *OnNext* was invoked 2 times. Exception raised.
5. +OnNext -OnCompleted +OnError +RefCount: Hangs after displaying 1 (probably because it wants to return to thread that is awaited). We can make it work (and raise exception) by using SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)

Anyway in case when observable is empty (no *OnNext* rised) we get exception even if *OnError* is not called and we don't have any exception inside observable logic. Thats why awaiting on observable is not good solution.

That is why I tried another solution using TaskCompletionSource

```
public async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    var observable = Observable.Create<int>(o =>
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("OnNext");
            o.OnNext(1);
            o.OnError(new Exception("exception in observable logic"));
            //o.OnCompleted();
        });
        return Disposable.Empty;
    });

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    observable.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i),
    e =>
    {
        //tcs.TrySetException(e);
        tcs.SetResult(false);
    },
    () => tcs.TrySetResult(true));

    Console.WriteLine("Awaiting...");
    await tcs.Task;
    Console.WriteLine("After Awaiting...");
}
```

It works ok in all scenarios and in case of *OnError* is invoked we could either use tcs.SetResult(false) and don't have information about exception details in outside method or we could use tcs.TrySetException(e) and be able to catch the exception in the outside method.

Can you suggest me if there is some better/cleaner solution or my second solution is the way to go?

EDIT

So I would like to know if there is a better solution than my second solution that will:

- not require to use *.Publish().RefCount()*
- not require additional subscription (what happens in await observable under the hood - OnNext is invoked 2 times)
- Of course I could wrap my solution in some async extension method for subscribing that returns Task

Comment: If ever you find yourself doing `return Disposable.Empty` inside `Observable.Create` then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @Enigmativity This is just an example and I think that this is not relevant to my problem. But anyway, what should I return in case I don't need to dispose anything?

Comment: At the very least create a `Subject<T>` in the `Observable.Create<T>` and then do `{ var subject = new Subject<T>(); var subscription = subject.Subscribe(o); /* your code */ return subscription;`.

Comment: Why should I create an instance of Subject<T> if I don't need this class inside Observable.Create method? If I don't need to dispose anything then I should return Disposable.Empty. I don't understand your point.

Comment: When you directly access the observer passed thru to the `.Observable.Create` you are causing the observable to run synchronously and thus can cause many of the observable operators to not behave as expected. To avoid this the rule should be that returning `Disposable.Empty` is bad.

Comment: Why are you so opposed to `Publish().RefCount()`?  Your other requirements basically scream 'hot observable'.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT:**

If you remove the subscription you can do the following:

```
await observable.Do(i => Console.WriteLine(i)).LastOrDefaultAsync();
```

As for your arbitrary requirements... Not having multiple subscriptions for a cold observable makes sense; so you publish it. Refusing to use `.Publish().Refcount()` doesn't make sense. I don't understand why you're rejecting a solution that solves your problem.

---

There's a lot there, but I'm assuming this is your main question:

> Anyway in case when observable is empty (no OnNext rised) we get
>   exception even if OnError is not called and we don't have any
>   exception inside observable logic. Thats why awaiting on observable is
>   not good solution.

`await observable` is the same as `await observable.LastAsync()`. So if there is no element, you get an exception. Imagine changing that statement to `int result = await observable;` What should the value of `result` be if there's no elements?

If you change `await observable;` to `await observable.LastOrDefaultAsync();` everything should run smoothly.

And yes, you should use `.Publish().Refcount()`

Comment: Yes, you are right, this might work but I would like some clean solution so that I would not have additional subscription like is in case of awaiting the observable. In case of await observable.LastOrDefaultAsync() I would probably have 2 additional subscriptions. Also I would like to avoid .Publish().Refcount() thats why I picked my second solution as the most appropriate and I wander it there is anything better?

Comment: Edited for new requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd clearly prefer the 2nd solution, because it only subscribes once.

But out of curiosity: what's the purpose of writing a method like this?
If it's to allow for configurable side effects, this would be equivalent:

```
public async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    Action<int> onNext = Console.WriteLine;

    await Task.Delay(1000);
    onNext(1);
    throw new Exception("exception in DoWork logic"); // ... or don't
}
```

Comment: My code is just an example to illustrate the problem. The case is that I could have some async code invoked in my observable subscription and it can return some or no elements and complete or error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ToTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229587(v=vs.103).aspx) extension method:

```
await observable.ToTask();
```

Comment: This fails if I don't invoke OnNext. Also it creates separate subscription.

Comment: There is no need to call `.ToTask()`. You can directly await and observable.